# Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 - Not sending out emails

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.9, transactional-email

Got a bit of a strange issue, regarding emails being sent, on our server it used to use postfix and there was a mail.log in /var/log but we have noticed that it has disappeared and is now using phpmail.log instead.

Is there a way we can get the mail log back? Or is there anything in phpmail that we could check and see why its not sending.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Template.php, is located in the path /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php  .
Find and lock the line "if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {" and  "if (false) {" under it. 
Eg.- 
//if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) { 
  if (false) { 

Now place an order and check. [Also you have to set order email address from Admin panel ]